# Can't decrypt DB with SQLCipher but works with SQLBrowser

Tags: sqlcipher, sqlcipher-android

I'm able to open a DB using custom parameters set to HMAC = SHA1, KDF = SHA1 and providing the raw key in SQL browser but when using this commands in the SQLCipher CLI I can't decrypt the database.

This is the list of commands I use :

```
PRAGMA key = "x'MYKEY'";
PRAGMA cipher_kdf_algorithm = PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1;
PRAGMA cipher_hmac_algorithm = HMAC_SHA1;

select count(*) from sqlite_master;
```

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by compiling my own version of sqlcipher. The one provided by Ubuntu wasn't recent enough.